# error in download file from sftp using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to download a file from the server. I am able to connect to the sftp , list all the files in the given directory. However after downloading the file seems to be corrupted . I am unable to open that. Also I get an error while downloading as below

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data.on is not a function
```

Here is the code

```
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client;
  sftp.connect(config).then(() => { 
    sftp.get(remotePath).then((data) => {
      var outFile = fs.createWriteStream('fileee.zip')
      outFile.on('data',function(response) {
        outFile.write(response);
      });
      outFile.on('close', function() {
        outFile.close();
      });
    });
  })
```

Comment: What module are you using? What is `data`? Obviously it doesn't have a `on()` function ...

Comment: @derpirscher I have updated the code

Comment: What are you doing with your outfile??? When the stream receives some data you are writing that very same data on the very same stream? No wonder your file is corrupted. Why not just using the suggested code from the docs like shown in my answer below?

Comment: Yes @derpirscher thank you. Your ans is working perfectly as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#sec-5-2-6)

```
let client = new Client();

let remotePath = '/remote/server/path/file.txt';
let dst = fs.createWriteStream('/local/file/path/copy.txt');

client.connect(config)
  .then(() => {
    return client.get(remotePath, dst);
  })
  .then(() => {
    client.end();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });
```

Don't know where you got the idea about `data.on()` ...

Comment: Now getting this "RuntimeError: abort(sftpConnect: Remote host has reset the connection: read ECONNRESET). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info."